# is it possible to authorize google service account from google account that is already authorized to have access on GS buckets?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-authentication, gsutil

I have a google (gmail) account that is already authorized to have READ access on Google Storage buckets. I am trying to access these buckets programmatically using gsutil. I created a service account that will have project-id, key-id, private-key, client-email etc..in a json file. Now, is it possible for me to authorize this service account as well to have access on GS buckets via my primary google account under which this service account is created or do I have approach the admin again to get access for the email-id associated with the service account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud IAM Member can be [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview):

1.Google Account (for end users)

2.Service account (for apps and virtual machines)

3.Google group, or a G Suite or Cloud Identity domain that can access a resource.

> The identity of a member is an email address associated with a user,
>   service account, or Google group; or a domain name associated with G
>   Suite or Cloud Identity domains.

According to the documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)

> Creating a service account is similar to adding a member to your
>   project, but the service account belongs to your applications rather
>   than an individual end user.

"it possible for me to authorize this service account as well to have access on GS buckets via my primary google account"

Please keep in mind that you can not authorize, only admin of the project can authorize.

In your case you have to create a new service account and approach the admin to give you the right permissions. The admin will add a new members to the project. Your gmail account and your service account are different members that can have different permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification Marian

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if it was useful for you, for greater visibility for community